# Row-level Triggers (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

My trigger works fine if I insert 1 row, but not if I insert more than one.  Working with SQL Server 2008 R2 and this is for a class project.  Oracle has a FOR EACH ROW setting, but I have not found something similar in SQL Server...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgRoom_HotelFloorName
ON Room
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE Room
SET Room.HotelFloorName = (
SELECT HotelFloor.HotelFloorName FROM HotelFloor
JOIN  Inserted
ON HotelFloor.HotelFloorID = Inserted.HotelFloorID
AND Room.RoomID = Inserted.RoomID);

END;
```

Here are the results of inserting 3 records; only the last one is updated. Based on the messages in SQL Server Management Studio, it looks like the other two were updated, but then got overwritten.

```
RoomID  RoomName    HotelFloorID    HotelID HotelFloorName
1          San Diego A       12           2 NULL
2          San Diego B       12           2 NULL
3          Laguna                17           2 Lower Lobby Level, South Tower
```

Thanks for whatever wisdom you can provide.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` has no `WHERE` clause so all rows are updated every time the trigger fires.

Comment: SQL Server does **NOT** have a `FOR EACH ROW` clause for triggers; triggers will always have to be written in a way so that they can deal with multiple rows in the `Inserted` and/or `Deleted` pseudo tables.

Comment: The missing WHERE clause is the answer. Can't figure out how to accept it as such, though.  Thanks.